# Noam Chomsky's first article (written at age 10)

Tags: publications

There are numerous online references (for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky#CITEREFLyons1978), [here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/noam-chomsky) and [here](https://www.alternet.org/2018/11/noam-chomsky-turns-90-how-controversial-activist-survived-become-one-most-influential-anarchists-us/)) to Noam Chomsky's first article, which was written at age 10 (in 1939) and was about the spread of Fascism following the fall of Barcelona during the Spanish Civil War.

Is the article itself available online?

(I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask; if not, any suggestions for a more appropriate place would be welcome.)

Comment: Why not ask him? He is pretty public.

Comment: You'll have more luck asking on the history stack, I think.  If you agree, flag your question and ask for migration, but read the history stack guidelines first.

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr** almost certainly not.

One of the references given in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky#CITEREFLyons1978) (Sperlich 2006,  available on the Internet Archive), states:

> [p. 13] Aged ten he contributed an **editorial article to his school newspaper** concerning the spread of fascism. He still remembers the first sentence as something like 'Austria falls, Czechoslovakia falls, and now Barcelona falls.'

(emphasis added). This suggests

- the venue was a school newspaper (not a published journal) (other sources mention the [Oak Lane Country Day School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_Lane_Day_School), which was famous (closed in 2010) and which *slightly* increases the chance that archival material is available somewhere)
- at the time of the interview (pre-2006), Chomsky apparently didn't have access to the article himself.

I agree that asking Chomsky himself is probably your best bet, or see if anyone in the [Oak Lane Country Day School Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/2204518792/posts/10158865332318793/) has any leads.  Temple University has a digital archive collection from the school but it appears to be only photos (including [one from 1940 that includes Chomsky](https://digital.library.temple.edu/digital/collection/p16002coll2/id/3068/rec/1)). You could contact the Temple University Libraries’ Special Collections Research Center (`scrc@temple.edu`) ...

---

Wolfgang B. Sperlich. Noam Chomsky. Reaktion Books, 2006. http://archive.org/details/noamchomsky00sper.